# Spring initialization of RandomGenerator across platforms

Tags: spring, ubuntu, windows-7, random

I am running JUnit tests on a Spring3 app on two different platforms (Win7 and Ubuntu PP). 
For testing/reproducibility purposes I have set the seed of my random generator in my application context

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.math3.random.MersenneTwister">
        <property name="seed" value="1111111" />
</bean>
```

Now this test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( { Config.APP_CONFIG_PATH })
public class StatTestAtomicInitOut {

@Autowired 
RandomGenerator rg;

@Test
public void testRandomGenerator() {

    Assert.assertEquals(9183, rg.nextInt(10000));

}

}
```

passes consistently in Windows7, but fails consistently on Ubuntu PP (java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<9183> but was:<9561>).

This other test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( { Config.APP_CONFIG_PATH })
public class StatTestAtomicInitIn {

 @Autowired 
 RandomGenerator rg;

 @Test
 public void testRandomGenerator() {

    rg.setSeed(new Long(1111111));
    Assert.assertEquals(9183, rg.nextInt(10000));

 }

}
```

passes consistently both on Windows7 and on Ubuntu PP.

Why does Spring initialization of the random generator on Ubuntu (but not on Win7)  yield results which are diffrent from those obtained setting the seed at runtime?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

aa

Comment: The Spring xml introduces some ambiguity as MersenneTwister.setSeed() is overloaded for long and int, while the explicit instruction specifies long. Hopefully this is a start, although I'm not sure why Spring would infer different constructors on different architectures.

Comment: Good point.Indeed, the following fails: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( { Config.APP_CONFIG_PATH })
public class MersenneTest {

 
 @Test
 public void testRandomGenerator() {
  int seed = 1111111;
  MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister();
  mt.setSeed(seed);
  Assert.assertEquals(9183, mt.nextInt(10000));

  
 }

} but it passes if one replaces int seed  with long seed. Any idea about how to tell Spring it should use long rather than int?

Comment: add 'L' as a suffix to the number.

Comment: I did it this way:<bean class="org.apache.commons.math3.random.MersenneTwister">
  <!-- <property name="seed" value="1111111" />  -->
  <constructor-arg type="long" value="1111111" />
</bean>. Now the tests pass both on Win7 and on Ubuntu. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @AndreaAlciato - put your finding as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this configuration

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.math3.random.MersenneTwister">  
    <constructor-arg type="long" value="1111111" />
</bean>
```

the tests pass on both platforms.
Thanks to  Tom McIntyre for putting me on the right track. 
Another possibility is

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.math3.random.MersenneTwister">
    <property name="seed" >
        <value type="long">1111111</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

for which the tests pass.

The somewhat academic question of why Spring chooses different default setters on different platforms remains unanswered. Curiously, for me at least, with the following configuration

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.math3.random.MersenneTwister">
    <property name="seed" >
        <value type="java.lang.Long">1111111</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

StatTestAtomicInitOut passes on win7, but fails on Ubuntu.